# how to define a certain value to equal to constant just for the first iteration?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, simultaneous

I have a the following code (as an example):

```
answ = []
for i in range(1, 3):
    x = y + 2
    y = 3 + x
    answ.append(y)
```

Where x and y are simultaneously determined. How can I determine them simultaneously? Or how can I assume that for the first loop y=0 (so x will equal to 2) and then starting from the second iteration 'y' = 3 + x.

Comment: You know that in your code, `y = 3 + x` is the same as `y = y + 5`?

Comment: Yes, I know.. That's just a simple example to solve the more complex problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `y` to 0 before the `for` loop:

```
answ = []
y = 0
for i in range(1, 3):
    x = y + 2
    y = 3 + x
append.answ(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 x, y = y + 2, 3 + x
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, `x` and `y` are local variables, meaning they are deleted at the end of each iteration of the `for` loop. If you want them to carry over from the previous iteration, you need to define `x` and `y` **outside** of the `for` loop. This puts them above and the scope of the loop, so they don't get redefined.

Another thing, your for loop runs 2 times, because computers count from 0 and don't include the last number. Because `i` is not used in your loop at all, it would be better to do:

```
for i in range(2):
    # code
```

But I am guessing that you want your loop to run three times, in which case you would write:

```
for i in range(3):
    # code
```

I also noticed that you wrote `append.answ(y)` instead of `answ.append(y)`. `append` is a member function of `answ`, so you would call it the second way.

Anyways, here is the final code for your program:

```
answ = []
x = 0
y = 0

for i in range(3):
    x = y + 2
    y = 3 + x

    answ.append(y)
```